# Знаки препинания и заглавные буквы в таблицах

Tags: пунктуация

Как обстоит дело с пунктуацией и заглавными буквами в таблицах? Нужно ли считать каждую клетку отдельным предложением? Или может наоборот?
На примере следующей таблички, пожалуйста.

```
              todo-list
┌─────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│Вынести мусор        │ в 12:00.       │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│Позвонить в колокола │ до 19:00.      │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│Убить Билла          │ в полночь.     │
└─────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере можно рекомендовать строчную букву для содержимого ячеек второго столбца, ибо грамматически оно подчинено содержимому соответствующих ячеек первого столбца. Точки не ставятся.

Comment: Кстати, спасибо за небанальные to-do. Улыбнулся. :) И, коли уж речь зашла о них, верное оформление заголовка таблицы: To-do list (с прописной буквы).

Answer (score 1):

Таблица оформлена некорректно: отсутствует наименование граф (столбцов), содержимое граф не должно быть грамматически связано друг с другом и, соответствено, должно писаться с прописной буквы, предлоги во второй графе не нужны, точки тоже.

Во втором пункте можно оставить предлог, написав его с большой буквы, а в первом и третьем достаточно указать "12:00" и "24:00" (либо "00:00").

Comment: Но ведь без предлогов будет непонятно, интервал это или конкретный момент времени.